# Web API Dev/Debug mode vs Live Mode Errors are different

Tags: c#, iis, webapi2

This is a real head scratcher for me.  I have a Windows Service that posts data to a Web API app.  If the Web API on my local development machine is turned off (simulating system down experience for my customer), I get a nice pretty error that looks like this:

[image]

However, when I publish the web api and windows service to a development lane IIS environment, I get the following:

[image]

Which is just the text version of:

[image]

The question I have is, what setting in IIS do I need to flip to suppress the native 404 Not found stock error message and just render the text I am getting back in the development environment?  I've played around with Custom Errors but that didnt seem to yield anything useful, but I will confess to being an IIS novice so I may have missed something.

Comment: Can I suggest to change the app pool identity of the web api in IIS to be on Local System(windows service I assume it works under local system), if windows service and web api are on the same server?

Comment: No joy.  Still same output.